# listen to keypress and add to input form

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a search filter to my website, and I would like it to be dynamic without clicking on the input form, i.e. listen to keystrokes.

currently I have the following code:

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<ul id="myUL">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Adele
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Vivian
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Lucy
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried adding the following to my script tag:

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    document.getElementById("myInput").value += event.key;
});
```

But:

1. it doesn't recognize backspace in order to delete from the search
   filter.
2. it doesn't search. I have to press the search box, which I want to eventually hide, in order for the filter to work.

I am pretty new to JS and would like to hear if anyone encountered this or something similar.

Thanks.

Comment: So, - what do you want to happen? https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/dbr1ku3e/ - naming things like "myFunction" isn't very descriptive. Can you explain that goals a little more?

Comment: When the keydown event fires there is no value in the input, tey the keyup event.

Comment: PS. you only have one Li Element in your list, so only the first <a> tag would be searched.

Comment: @user3094755 my mistake for messing the li tags, I fixed it! however keyup doesn't work as well

Comment: I was asking for you to explain what you want to happen. Can you do that? Step by step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not encouraging this interface pattern... but I am encouraging you to have fun - and be creative / which you are doing.

Here's how I'd think about it / loosely. https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/dbr1ku3e/

```js
// "I am trying to add a search filter to my website"

// "and I would like it to be dynamic without clicking on the input form, i.e. listen to keystrokes."

// (1) keep a string in memory - of what is typed - (allow for backspace etc...)

// (2) keyup - filter the menu - based on the string + (3) render the updated list ?

const queryLetters = []; // not really a "string though" - but maybe easier to work with!
let queryString = '';
const $output = document.querySelector('.current-search');


function buildSearchString(letterArray) {
  var string = '';
  letterArray.forEach( function(letter) {
    string += letter; // yes - you could also use map and split instead etc.
  })
  console.log(`Search for "${string}"`);
  return string;
}


function noteQuery(pressedKey) {
  if (pressedKey == "Backspace") { // BUT WHAT ABOUT *shift* and other stuff... 
    queryLetters.pop(); // remove last letter from array
  } else {
    queryLetters.push(pressedKey);
  }
  queryString = buildSearchString(queryLetters);
  $output.textContent = queryString;
}


const $menu = document.querySelector('[rel="filtered-menu"]');
function collectMenuInfo() {
  // go get the HTML stuff... and then we can use it to rerender the list - instead of hiding and showing things....
  // assuming this might be server-side rendered to start...
  const menuItems = $menu.querySelectorAll('a');
  console.log(menuItems);
  const itemArray = Array.from(menuItems).map( function(item) {
    return { // from NodeList to array... make a new array of 'items'
      text: item.textContent,
      href: item.href,
    };
  });
  console.log(itemArray);
  window.menuItems = itemArray;
}
collectMenuInfo();


function renderMenu(stuff) {
  var filteredItems = stuff.filter( function(thing) {
  var lowercase = thing.text.toLowerCase();
    return lowercase.includes(queryString);
  })
  var template = '';
  filteredItems.forEach( function(item) {
    template += `<a href='${item.href}' class='z'>${item.text}</a>`;
  });
  $menu.innerHTML = template;
}


document.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  noteQuery(event.key);
  renderMenu(menuItems); // could combine these into a handler -
});
```

```css
span {
  font-style: italic;
  color: green;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<p>Type to search for: <span class="current-search"></span></p>

<nav class="menu" rel="filtered-menu">
  <a href="#adele">Adele</a>
  <a href="#carl">Carl</a>
  <a href="#sheriff">Sheriff</a>
  <a href="#derek">Derek</a>
  <a href="#vivian">Vivian</a>
  <a href="#lucy">Lucy</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: this is actually similar to what I did eventually, but your code gave me some ideas. Thankns!

Comment: If you end up getting your project online, drop a link! I'd love to see it in action. : )

Answer (score 0):

Use the onchange event. Whenever the value of the input changes the event is fired
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp